# How to balance between running search in frontend and backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, search, full-text-search

I have an angular app that runs on a Rails app api.

I do most of my searches using Angular in the frontend, but I feel like there is going to be a bottleneck when I reach a huge number of users.

Should I go with the backend Rails api search or stick with the frontend even if my users reach 5000 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have 5000 users in a searchable list, you're likely going to need to handle things on the server. Obviously hard to answer without more I for about your app, but once you start getting into thousands of potential angular bindings, it starts to crawl.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, this the kind of answer I was looking for. I don't really have that much more, it's as simple as a directory of names and users in my app.